# Saving state in a Windows Store app when logged in with a local account

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, roaming, microsoft-account

I'm new to Windows Store app development and Windows 8 in general and I'm working on an app.

I see that there are 2 types of accounts to log in to win8 with: a Microsoft account and a local account.

I also see that I have 2 data stores I can use to save persistently: the local data store and the roaming data store.

My question:
Does it make sense to use the roaming data store for a user that is logged in on a local account?
Does the account type matter for this decision?
I assume my app will be used by both types of users.

Comment: Seems all Microsoft samples happily write to RoamingFolder without checking for a local user, so I'm assuming you can write data to there and the data stored there will automatically start to sync when/if the local user later is connected to a Microsoft account.

Comment: how's the local user going to get the app? short of sideloading, he/she can visit the store but to install an app the account must be tied to a Microsoft account.